# How do I view a multipage web table on a single page

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, script, html

I am trying to navigate a web table that runs into thousands of pages. Unfortunately it is displayed 50 on a page and I am tired of clicking the next button.

I want to view all the pages on a single page so I can easily search for what I am looking for.

Are there any browser extensions that can sort this out?

I'd appreciate an easy way out

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any browser extensions that can sort this out?

No - at least, none that I know of, it would involve downloading dozens of pages and stitching tables together or at least concatenating the results intelligently.

> I'd appreciate an easy way out

There are ways out, but I wouldn't describe them as easy. If you can write programs or scripts, you can probably automate fetching the pages and concatenating the results. You can probably use `wget` or `curl` for part of this but if I was doing this I'd use a scripting language (e.g. Perl, but probably almost any scripting language would do the job).

Comment: Thanks! I have a red time comprehending HTML. So I was actually looking for a non programming solution. I am just too lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions would have to be specific for the sites you visit so chances that a extension for your site exists might be low.

You however can often change the number of items per page. Sometimes there are no server-side constraints on the number chosen by the client, so you can just tell it to give you something like the first 100000 and thus get 100000 items on one page. So look for a parameter in the URL that corresponds to the number of items on one page and change that to a bigger value. YMMV

Comment: No ranges exist in the url.